# Angular: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get players list to load while user selects a game, however I'm getting Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at m.$scope.getPlayers (campaigns-players.js:104)

I've used it similar on another page however it gives me this error on this page, so I'm not really sure what I've done wrong this time. Appreciate the help!

HTML;

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">List of Games</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="gameList" ng-model="game" ng-change="getPlayers()">
                            <option ng-repeat="game in allGames" ng-value="{{game.id}}"> {{game.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">List of Players</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="ccmonth" ng-model="selectedPlayer">
                            <option ng-repeat="player in players" ng-value="{{player.id}}"> {{player.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Player Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="entityNameUpdate" ng-model="entityNameUpdate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Which game player in?</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="updatedGamePlayer" ng-model="updatedGame">
                            <option ng-repeat="updatedGame in allGames" ng-value="{{updatedGame.id}}"> {{updatedGame.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="save()"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
                            Save</button>
                    </div>
```

JS File

```
//main.js
angular
    .module('app', ['multipleSelect', 'ngSanitize'])
    .controller('adspacesController', adspacesController)
//, [multipleSelect]
//convert Hex to RGBA
adspacesController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$timeout'];

function adspacesController($scope, $http, $location, $timeout) {
    var apiUrl = adminService;
    var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    var config = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "" + "0481383f",
            "Accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "contentType": 'application/json',
        }
    };

    $scope.getAllGames = function () {
        var url = apiUrl+"/game/all";
        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data) {
                        debugger;
                        $scope.allGames = response.data;
                    } else {
                        $scope.showErrorMessage("No data found");
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    $scope.responseErrorCheck(error);
                }
            );
    };

    $scope.getPlayers = function () {
        debugger;
        var url = apiUrl + "/game/" + $scope.game.id;
        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                debugger;
                    if (response.data) {
                        $scope.adspaces = response.data;
                    } else {
                        $scope.showErrorMessage("Player not found");
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    $scope.responseErrorCheck(error);
                }
            );
    };

    $scope.pageLoading = function (name) {
        $scope.getRules();
        $scope.getCategories();
        $scope.getAllGames();
        $scope.assetImageShow = false;
        $scope.game='';

    }
```

Comment: Your `$scope.game` is not defined, please add more code to the question

Comment: how many controllers do you have?

Comment: I have added more detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution 1***

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="gameList" ng-model="game" ng-change="getPlayers()">
<option ng-repeat="game in allGames" ng-value="{{game.id}}"> {{game.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In getPlayers()

```
var url = apiUrl + "/game/" + $scope.game;
```

**Solution 2**:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="gameList" ng-model="game" ng-change="getPlayers()">
<option ng-repeat="game in allGames" ng-value="{{game}}"> {{game.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In getPlayers()

```
var url = apiUrl + "/game/" + $scope.game.id;
```

Run the following snippet

```js
  angular
    .module('myapp',[])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope){
     $scope.game;
     $scope.allGames=[
     {
       name:"GTA",
       id:1
     },
     {
      name:"PUBG",
       id:2
     }
     ];
     $scope.getPlayers= function () {
        var url = "apiUrl/game/" + $scope.game.id;
        console.log(url);
    }});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" class="card-body">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">List of Games</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="gameList" ng-model="game" ng-change="getPlayers()">
        <option ng-repeat="game in allGames" ng-value="game"> {{game.name}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks perfectly fine here however it is giving me the same error

Comment: How many controllers do you have? Can you show us the project structure? and where you are using this code

Comment: I have added some more detail to my post!

Comment: Do I need to use   $scope.game=''; at the page loading function?

Comment: it doesnt matter . Just write $scope.game;

Comment: Does it matter where I put that?

Comment: Sorry it has been going so long but shall I write that in pageLoading function?

Comment: write it in start of controller before var api url

Comment: Welcome... If you found this answer useful please upvote it and mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-value here from game to game.id

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">List of Games</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="gameList" ng-model="game" ng-change="getPlayers()">
        <option ng-repeat="game in allGames" ng-value="{{game.id}}"> {{game.name}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

In js code define $scope.game;

```
$scope.game;
 $scope.getPlayers = function () {
        var url = apiUrl + "/game/" + $scope.game.id;
        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data) {
                        $scope.players = response.data;
                    } else {
                        $scope.showErrorMessage("Player not found");
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    $scope.responseErrorCheck(error);
                }
            );
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However it is still giving me the same error